# KERAS-Instructions for updating: Colocations handled automatically by placer

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, tf.keras

I am Using Keras Library For my Neural Network error. While using Dropout I got the 3 following warning

```
WARNING:tensorflow: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Colocations handled automatically by placer.

WARNING:tensorflow: calling dropout (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) with keep_prob is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Rate should be set to `rate = 1 - keep_prob`. 

WARNING:tensorflow: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use tf.cast instead.
```

This How i use the dropout in the model

```
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
```

Although it is a warning, I am worried about it. Previously, I got another warning when I use dropout like the following

```
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

What should I do to get rid of these warnings? can anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really get rid of these warnings, they are not generated from your code, but from internal keras code that calls `tf.nn.dropout`. These warnings are not meant for you but to the keras team, they have to update the tensorflow backend to remove the warnings.

The only way to get rid of the warnings is to edit keras' source code.